# Get sample document of percentile aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

Is is possible using elasticsearch to get an example of a document representative of a percentile calculated in the aggregation ?

```
"agg_percentile": {
    "percentiles": {
        "field": "my_value",
        "percents": [
            10,
            50,
            95
        ]
    }
}
```

given this aggregation, I would like to get an example of one document inside each of the percentile.

For instance:

```
"values": [
     {
          "key": 1.0,
          "value": 1462.8400000000001,
          "hit": {
             "_source":...
         }
      },
```

So you would have a sample of what a document resulting in this percentile is.

Is it possible in one query ? 
I could always do a second query search for `my_value` bigger than the 9th percentile and smaller than the 11th. But I would like to do it in one query.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Question is not clear enough. can you be more specific and provide some example of what you need.

Comment: edited the questions

Answer (score 0):

Try [Top hits Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html):

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "agg_percentile": {
      "percentiles": {
        "field": "my_value",
        "percents": [
          10,
          50,
          95
        ],
        "keyed": false   # --> pay attention, you now will get each percentile in seperate bucket
      },
      "aggregations":{
        "top_hits":{
          "size": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that we set the `keyed` argument to `false`.

As described in the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-percentile-aggregation.html) - it will separate each percentile to individual bucket - what gives us the ability to add another level of aggregation - `Top Hits` for each percentile.